# Visual SourceSafe Reconciliation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

What would be the ideal reconciliation mechanism between what is there in VSS 6.0 and what is there in our production environment? Our company outsources all its application support & development activities and are dependent on the vendor to provide the solution file to be kept in our VSS.
We do have quite a number of projects and would like to understand on how to go about with reconciling the files which are under VSS and what has been actually deployed in production.

Comment: And what is there in your production environment? How are we supposed to know?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need some form of file based compare, as VSS is a file repository.

I therefore recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), check-out the VSS trunk/latest, and compare the directory with production. You can filter out the .vss files (I think they where called that) and see what new/older, or missing on one side etc.

It can also compare locale file to a FTP destination, depends how you access "production" really.

Comment: BeyondCompare is great, but costs.  If you need a free/open source equivalent, try WinMerge. Here: http://winmerge.org/

Comment: costs, ouch if $30USD or $50USD is too much, some serious questions needed to be asked, like is there a next pay check?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 6 comes with a file compare utility, WinDiff. I use this in conjunction with the file compare built into SourceSafe to compare and contrast between live, updated, development and SourceSafe source.
You can do a SourceSafe differences on a project by right clicking on the project and selecting "Show Differences...".